# Is there a way to count the number of times my heroku app has been visited?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have my app running on heroku, how can I find the number of hits the app gets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not something that Heroku provide out of the box and I imagine in the majority of cases people would incorporate something like Google Analytics to track page views, visits and visitors.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that Google Analytics was free up to 10 million views per month.